# Find the greatest common divisors

Tags: number-theory

I am given the following exercise:

- If $p$ is a prime and $(a,b)=p$,calculate $(a^2,b^2), (a^2,b)$

That's what I have tried:

- Both $a$ and $b$ contain $p$ and at least one of them contains $p$ with exponent $1$.
  The two canonical forms of $a$ and $b$ have not an other common prime.

  So,it can be

  1. $a=p \cdot p_1^{a_1} \cdot p_2^{a_2} \cdots p_k^{a_k} \text{ and } b=p^{d} \cdot q_1^{d_1} \cdot q_2^{d_2} \cdots q_m^{a_m}$
  2. $a=p^{a_0} \cdot p_1^{a_1} \cdots p_k^{a_k} \text{ and } b=p \cdot q_1^{b_1} \cdots q_m^{b_m}$

where $p_i \neq q_j \forall i,j$

So:

1. $(a^2,b^2)=p^{\min\{2,2d \}}=p^2$
2. $(a^2,b^2)=p^{\min \{ 2,2a_0\}}=p^2$

   1. $(a^2,b)=\left\{\begin{matrix}
      p,d=1\\ 
      p^2,d \geq 2
      \end{matrix}\right. $
   2. $(a^2,b)=p$

   Could you tell me if it is right?

Comment: Seems right to me, if a bit long of a proof.

Comment: Looks about right.

Comment: Typo at the very end, you want $(a^2,b)$ not $(a^2,p)$.

Comment: Nice,thank you all very much!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, $(a^2,b^2)=p^2$ which is obtained by counting powers of $p$ in $a^2$ and $b^2$.

For $(a^2,b)$ there are two answers:
$$
(a^2,b)=p^2,\, \mathrm{ for\, example,\, } a=p,\ b=p^2,
$$
$$
(a^2,b)=p,\, \mathrm{ for\, example,\, } a=p,\ b=p.
$$

There is no more cases, because $(a^2,b)|(a^2,b^2)$ and $(a,b)|(a^2,b)$. Hence $(a^2,b)$ is $p$ or $p^2$.

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is correct. You may find it instructive to compare it to this more general method.

Note $\ \ (A,B) = p\iff A,B = pa,pb,\  (a,b) = 1.$

Thus $\,(A^2,B) = (p^2 a^2,pb) = p(p\color{#0a0}{a^2,b}) = p\color{#c00}{(p,b)},\ $ by $\,(a,b)=1\,\Rightarrow\,\color{#0a0}{(a^2,b)=1}\,$ by Euclid's Lemma.

So $\,\ (A^2,B^2) = (p^2a^2,p^2b^2) = p^2(a^2,b^2) = p^2,\ $ by $\,\color{#0a0}{(a^2,b)=1}\,\Rightarrow\,(a^2,b^2)=1\,$ by Euclid's Lemma.

**Remark** $\ $ Notice that the above method eliminates the case analysis, reducing it to $\, \color{#c00}{(p,b)} = p\,$ or $\,1\,$ if $\,p\,$ is prime. But the above proof works for any $\,p.$ In fact the above proof works more generally in any gcd domain, i.e. any domain where gcds exist. This is more general than using the *existence* and *uniqueness* of prime factorizations, since some gcd domains have no primes at all, for example the ring of all algebraic integers, where $\,\alpha \,=\, \sqrt \alpha\sqrt \alpha,\,$ so there are no irreducibles, so no primes.